# Running SonarQube on internal Web Server

Tags: web-services, iis, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am trying to make Sonarqube working on a virtual machine, IP 192.168.0.150, running on a production server (Win Server 2012 R2). I need also to access it from the Internet. Thus, I created a new website in IIS on the Physical server enabling the reverse proxy and redirecting everything to 192.168.0.150. This apparently works: I can access successfully the dashboard from any remote pc.
The problem is: when i try to login, sonarqube redirects to 192.168.0.150. As you can easily imagine this blows up everything from a remote pc.
I tried everything in sonar.web.host and sonar.host.url but nothing.
I tried an Outbound rule in IIS to overwrite 192.168.0.150 with my website address but it doesn't work with gzip compression.
What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: I can't help you because I don't know IIS enough, but just for the record: there are great chances that the issue is on IIS configuration because we are using SonarQube behind a NGinx proxy on http://nemo.sonarqube.org and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please let me know your sonar an nginx configuration? It may help me a lot to identify the problem.

Comment: I don't have it, it's on our Infra team side. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

I had to check  "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" option in  IIS -> Machine -> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings.

Comment: I'm having issues trying to set up the same configuration. The docs I've seen don't seem to cover all the IIS settings (i.e. the one you had problems with). Would you be willing/are you able to share IIS configurations? TIA

Comment: What do you enter in "Reverse proxy:" ?